# Random records for a row

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I have the following table strvals() with data. I'm looking to randomly choose 2 rows from strval() table and populate table S1 in a loop.

I want something like this

```
Create table s1(id primary key,strval1, strval2) as 
   select level,random_rec(strvals), random_rec(strvals) 
   from dual 
   connect by level<=10;
```

The caveat is the column strval1 has to be different THEN strval2 for each row.

```
Valid output
1, 'AAAA', 'BBBB'
2, 'CCCC', 'BBBB'
3, 'CCCC', 'AAAA'
```

Not valid

```
1, 'AAAA', 'AAAA'

Create table strvals(
  strval varchar2(4),
  constraint pk_strval primary key (strval)   
);

insert into strvals 
values(  
 'AAAA'   
);

insert into strvals 
values(  
 'BBBB'   
);

insert into strvals 
values(  
 'CCCC'   
);
```

Comment: Thank you I tapped the code tag and thought that would format the code. Do I need <> or [] tags for formatting

Answer (score 1):

Getting a random string from a table can be tricky.  One method is to use correlated subqueries -- the correlation clause ensures that the subquery is not "optimized" to run only once.

So, here is one method:

```
select id, strval,
       (select s2.strval
        from strvals s2
        where s2.strval <> x.strval and x.id > 0
        order by dbms_random.random fetch first 1 row only
       ) as strval2
from (select id,
             (select strval
              from strvals
              where x.id > 0
              order by dbms_random.random fetch first 1 row only
             ) as strval
     from (select level as id
           from dual 
           connect by level < 25
          ) x
    ) x;
```

And [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51f324af39c79d44fea6ab06b00553ea) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for your help and expertise

Comment: "Thanks" in the comment but even didn't upvote the answer :) So upvote from me

Answer (score 0):

To reduce a number of slow dbms_random.value in case of many rows, I would suggest to use this technique:

```sql
with 
 rand as (select row_number()over(order by dbms_random.value()) n,strval from strvals)
,cnt as (select count(*) m from rand)
,generator as (select level id,  ceil(dbms_random.value()*cnt.m) rnd from cnt connect by level<=10)
select generator.id, rand.strval
from generator
     join rand on rand.n=generator.rnd;
```

As you can see, I sort the table `strvals` once by dbms_random.value (`rand` view), so each row has own random integer number, then I count them to get maximum N. And then I calculate random N for each generated row so we can join `rand` view using hash join.

**Update**: for 2 strvals: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=55342cd76fcc4d625633aa65681edd8c)

```sql
with 
 rand as (select row_number()over(order by dbms_random.value()) n,strval from strvals)
,cnt as (select count(*) m from rand)
,generator as (
    select
       level id,
       ceil(dbms_random.value()*cnt.m) rnd1,
       ceil(dbms_random.value()*cnt.m) rnd2
    from cnt connect by level<=10
 )
select
   generator.id,
   rnd1.strval,
   rnd2.strval
from generator
     join rand rnd1 on rnd1.n=generator.rnd1
     join rand rnd2 on rnd2.n=generator.rnd2;
```

**Update2**: now with 2 strvals: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=074483dd831eaa60d65b56d3b909aaf6)

```sql
with 
 rand as (
    select
        row_number()over(order by dbms_random.value()) n
        ,s1.strval strval1
        ,s2.strval strval2
    from strvals s1
         join strvals s2
            on s1.strval!=s2.strval
 )
,cnt as (select count(*) m from rand)
,generator as (
    select
       level id,
       ceil(dbms_random.value()*cnt.m) rnd
    from cnt connect by level<=10
 )
select
   generator.id,
   rand.strval1,
   rand.strval2
from generator
     join rand on rand.n=generator.rnd
order by 1
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and expertise. My requirement is to have 2 strings as part of the output ie 1,'AAAA', 'BBBB'
2, 'CCCC', 'BBBB'
3, 'CCCC', 'AAAA'

Comment: ah, ok, done - please have a look at the updated answer

Comment: ah, sorry, I missed another requirement - to have different strvals... not sure if my approach will be effective for this...

Comment: @Beefstu ok, done with 2 strvals. Please check the latest update

Comment: Thank you for your help and eloquent solution. Hopefully I can take it the rest of the way myself.